# Eigenfaces shows emptyblack image in matlab

Tags: matlab

i have a set of 17 face grayscale pictures..and when try to view it i get a black images instead of ghost like pictures.

[image: matlab image]

```
    input_dir = 'images';
image_dims = [60, 60];

filenames = dir(fullfile(input_dir, '*.jpg'));
num_images = numel(filenames);
images = [];
for n = 1:num_images
    filename = fullfile(input_dir, filenames(n).name);
    img = imresize(imread(filename),[60,60]);
    if n == 1
        images = zeros(prod(image_dims), num_images);
    end
    images(:, n) = img(:);
end

% Trainig

% steps 1 and 2: find the mean image and the mean-shifted input images
mean_face = mean(images, 2);
shifted_images = images - repmat(mean_face, 1, num_images);

% steps 3 and 4: calculate the ordered eigenvectors and eigenvalues
[evectors, score, evalues] = princomp(images');

% step 5: only retain the top 'num_eigenfaces' eigenvectors (i.e. the principal components)
num_eigenfaces = 20;
evectors = evectors(:, 1:num_eigenfaces);

% step 6: project the images into the subspace to generate the feature vectors
features = evectors' * shifted_images;
```

and to see the eignevalues i used this code

```
figure;
for n = 1:num_eigenfaces
    subplot(2, ceil(num_eigenfaces/2), n);
    evector = reshape(evectors(:,n), image_dims);
    imshow(evector);
end
```

i dont think it was suppose to be like this. can someone point out what i did wrong?

Comment: what are the dimensions of shifted_images

Comment: am not sure if this is what u need ...but matlab says (3600X17) and i have 17 training images.

Answer (score 0):

You should check each step in the code and make sure they pass sanity checks.  My guess is this

```
features = evectors' * shifted_images;
```

Should be this

```
features = shifted_images * evectors;
```

Which makes me wonder if shifted_images has the correct dimensions.  The evectors should be a matrix where each column represents a component vector.  The matrix will be [pics x n].  The shifted images should be a [pixcount x pics] matrix.  "pixcount" is the amount of pixels in each picture and "pics" is the number of pictures.  If `evectors' * shifted_images` works without a dimensions error, I wonder if one quantity isn't being calculated correctly.  I think this transpose is the culprit:

```
princomp(images');
```

Comment: i tried that and i get this error Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

`Error in PCA (line 32)
features =  shifted_images * evectors;`

Answer (score 0):

Try scaling the image:

```
for i=1:num_eigenfaces
    subplot(1,7,i);
    image=reshape(evectors(:,i), image_dims);
    image=image';
    %scale image to full scale
    imshow(image, []);
end
```